# What is the order of a rotation group

Tags: group-theory

I was recapping some question on groups for my upcoming exams and chanced upon a question asking for the order of a rotation group $$C_{8}$$.
Is the order of a rotation group 2n or $$\frac{2 \pi}{n}$$?

Comment: It looks like you mean $C_8$, the cyclic group of order $8$. This group has an order of $8$.  You may be confusing this with the dihedral group in which, depending on your notation, we might say that $D_8$ has order $16$.

Comment: Note that the **order** of any group is necessarily an **integer**.  Review the definition of order to see why this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

The order of a group is always a positive integer, so no group will have order $2\pi / n$ (for $n$ integer). Remember that the order of a (finite) group is the number of elements in the underlying set. The order of the cyclic group $C_n$ is $n$. I assume that you mean the group $\mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z}$. The group $C_n$ has exactly $n$ elements. Specifically in my notation
$$
\mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z} = \{[0], [1] , \dots , [n-1]\}
$$
where $[m]$ is the equivalence class $m + n\mathbb{Z}$.

Another way to realize this group is with each element being a rotation by $2\pi /n$. Again you have exactly $n$ elements. Remember in particular that the identity element is the rotation that does nothing.

Comment: There was a typo. It has been corrected

Comment: @Mathematicing: Got it. I updated my answer.